# EL Expression, set var if test condition is true

Tags: el, jsp-tags

I have the following code block within my TAG file -

(See comment inside code block for my question)

```
<c:forEach var="headerTab" items="${KualiForm.headerNavigationTabs}" varStatus="status">
   <c:if test="${headerTab.headerTabDisplayName != 'S2S'}">
      <c:choose>
         <c:when test="${headerTab.headerTabDisplayName == 'Key Personnel'}">

                  // (Set the value of the var evaluated in the test above here)
                  // How do I do the following using EL Notation:
                  // headerTab.headerTabDisplayName = 'Some other string';

         </c:when>
      </c:choose>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the [c:set JSTL Tag](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/set.html)? It should be something like this:

```
<c:set target="headerTab" property="headerTabDisplayName" 
    value="Some other string"/>
```